# How to set copyPixels to ignore transparent pixels?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have a BitmapData object with transparency (the sourceBitmapData parameter). Every time I use copyPixels() to copy it onto another BitmapData object the transparent pixels replace whatever is beneath them. I would like the copyPixels() function to simply ignore these fully transparent pixels (0x00) and NOT copy them.

Any ideas?

BTW, I've tried setting the alphaMerge to true but that doesn't solve the issue - the whole source object just goes black and ignores ALL transparency.

EDIT:

Here are the code snippets;

```
var b:UIComponent = new UIComponent();
    b.graphics.beginFill(color, opacity);
    b.graphics.drawCircle(size * 2, size * 2, size);
    b.graphics.endFill();

    shape = new BitmapData(size * 4, size * 4, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
    shape.draw(b);
    rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, size * 4, size * 4);
    shape.applyFilter(shape, rect, new Point(0, 0), new BlurFilter(20, 20) );
```

It creates a graphics object (circle in this case) and copies it to the source bitmap and then applies the blur filter.

```
drawBuffer.copyPixels(shape, rect, pnt, null, null, false);
```

After that, it applies the resulting image, several times, over drawBuffer. If alphaMerge is set to true, shape looks like a black blob - it seems that all alpha information is simply ignored and the alpha value is set to 0xFF (note: this is my speculation based on how it looks, I didn't verify it). On the other hand, if alphaMerge is set to false, the transparency is all there, except it overwrites whatever is beneath it (the pixels in drawBuffer) into transparent pixels.

Just in case you need the code for drawBuffer as well:

```
drawBuffer = new BitmapData(bitmapData.width, bitmapData.height, true, 0);
drawCanvas.graphics.beginBitmapFill(drawBuffer, null, false, true);
drawCanvas.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, drawBuffer.width, drawBuffer.height);
drawCanvas.graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: alphaMerge should do just that. Are you sure the images are 32-bit with transparency? Can you show us the code for both the target and source BMD?

Comment: What if you draw Bitmap with source bitmapData into destination? This will take transparency into account.

Comment: You mean BitmapData.draw() ? It's too slow for what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried copying your code into a blank project. It works fine for me with some sample values. Something else is wrong.

Copy this into a blank FLA:

```
var color:uint = 0xff0000;
var opacity:Number = 0.8;
var size:Number = 50;

var b:Sprite = new Sprite();
b.graphics.beginFill(color, opacity);
b.graphics.drawCircle(size * 2, size * 2, size);
b.graphics.endFill();

// draw semitransparent object from "b" to shape
var shape:BitmapData = new BitmapData(size * 4, size * 4, true, 0x00FFFFFF);
shape.draw(b);
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, size * 4, size * 4);
shape.applyFilter(shape, rect, new Point(0, 0), new BlurFilter(20, 20) );
var pnt:Point = new Point;


// create drawBuffer with yellow (to indicate transparency)
var drawBuffer:BitmapData;
drawBuffer = new BitmapData(300, 300, true, 0xffffff00);

// copy to drawBuffer (preserving transparency)
drawBuffer.copyPixels(shape, rect, pnt, null, null, true);

// using drawCanvas, put drawBuffer to screen
var drawCanvas:Sprite = new Sprite;
drawCanvas.graphics.beginBitmapFill(drawBuffer, null, false, true);
drawCanvas.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, drawBuffer.width, drawBuffer.height);
drawCanvas.graphics.endFill(); 
addChild(drawCanvas);
```

(Note I have passed in `true` into copyPixels's mergeAlpha.)

Comment: I've used your code and after some further testing, I found out that the problem was not in the copyPixels() parameters after all. Rather, a certain loop that was supposed to run copyPixels() about 100 times per frame was doing its job - by copying the same shape object a 100 times over in the same place (rather than in different places), which made it look like there was no transparency. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want mergeAlpha to be true:

```
drawBuffer.copyPixels(shape, rect, pnt, null, null, true);
```

Since this isn't working for you, double check the contents of the bitmap. You can do this by adding it to the stage directly, guaranteeing that you are seeing the true contents:

```
var b:Bitmap = new Bitmap(shape);
stage.addChild(b);
```

If this bitmap appears correct, perhaps you are copying the bitmap in more than once without clearing the target.

Also change `UIComponent` to `Sprite` or similar. I'm not familiar with `UIComponent` but you don't appear to be using any of its functionality.

Comment: I've already tested the shape bitmap and it indeed looks the way it's supposed to. However, when I copy it (via copyPixels) to drawBuffer, it either: 

a) copies transparent pixels over regular ones when alphaMerge is set to false

b) ignores all alpha data and instead treats the whole shape as if it had maximum alpha (0xFF)

Perhaps I should mention this as well - I applied a blur filter to shape before adding it to drawBuffer (that's how I got the transparent pixels).

Comment: I suggest you try a simplest case scenario in an entirely different project. `mergeAlpha` has never ignored the alpha data in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something obvious, but copyPixel does just what it says - copies pixels. It completely ignores what is underneath, so any non 100% transparent pixel (with merging set to true) will be overridden by your pixel. Considering you have a pixel in place, 0xFFFF00FF (a red one) if you copy into its place a pixel 0x4400FF00 the result will be overwriting, not drawing - 0x4400FF00.

Comment: that's only true if `mergeAlpha` is false. I've had plenty of success drawing in the normal way with `mergeAlpha` set to true.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your attempts you had the following line:

drawBuffer = new BitmapData(300, 300, true, 0xffffff00);

Try changing the alpha value of the color input, like this:

drawBuffer = new BitmapData(300, 300, true, 0x00ffff00);

-It's a minor change, but it may get you where you want to go.

-xprdq

Comment: There was already an accepted answer from well over two years ago on this one. If you're looking for old, unanswered questions, please browse here: http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered